# Is this spam or just a bad choice of random text?

Tags: discussion, spam

I just [edited a question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47781858/revisions) which contained in a code example:

> var myString = "Welcome to Example books. The Example website is www.example.com. Visit the Example website today. Thanks for buying Example";

where "Example" and "example.com" were the name and URL of a website that sells programming books. I can't really make up my mind whether this is an elaborate attempt at spamming, or just an ill-advised choice of random text. Should I have raised a spam flag?

Comment: Wrox is an established publisher of programming books. Nobody spams a web site that teaches programmers how to program, that would be like teaching somebody how to use kryptonite.

Comment: Example.com is an internet-standard domain for use in examples, see [RFC-2606](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) and [RFC-6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know, I changed the URL to example.com.

Comment: @m69 Yes, I misread your question and hadn't looked at the linked edit.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think you did the right thing. The name of the website and its URL are irrelevant to the question, and the example.com makes it clear it's a 'dummy' URL.

Unless the author repeatedly shows this behaviour, there's no reason to assume they are spamming. It's more likely just a project they are currently working on.

Comment: Indeed; I just checked out the user's profile, and I see no other problematic behaviour.

Comment: The only thing I would have left was the code, `wroxCount` doesn't hurt anything but a novice might not spot the change then when answers reference `example` the OP is still confused.

Comment: @AshleyMedway *"`wroxCount` doesn't hurt anything"* - of course it does. Words have meaning; you can't just interchange words for random unrelated ones and expect it not to confuse anybody. It's clear that a `wroxCount` is a count of `wrox`s; if you use that name for something that's actually a count of `example`s, then a reader is naturally going to ask "wait, what's this a count of?" and "WTF is a wrox?".

Comment: _WTF is a wrox?_ **w**ebsite **r**enamed t**o** e**x**ample!

Answer (score 91):

It's not spam, but it wasn't random text either. The code was copied from the textbook [Beginning JavaScript](https://books.google.com/books?id=SjekBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT217&lpg=PT217).

Comment: Oh, that explains it.

Comment: I think a rollback would be in order *plus* a new edit pointing to the origin of the code

Comment: Haha, nice catch!

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer.

Comment: @brasofilo Example.com is meant for this so I disagree that it should be rolled back.

Comment: @EpicKip, I'm putting more emphasis on being faithful to the source of the code than converting it to a generic template. Maybe a balance is possible...

Comment: @brasofilo Maybe a good solution is keeping example.com but adding a reference/link to the original. That way people know where it's from but it won't be seen as possible spam.